# What does the question mean by 'find all the possible values' of $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, parametrization

I'm working on some past exam papers and I wanted to see if I'm thinking of the following in the correct way;

Given a contour integral $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}dz$ I want to find all of it's possible values given that $\gamma$ is the semi-circle starting at $1$ and going to $-1$

My thinking is that as the radius of the semicircle is $1$ then $|z|=1$ and so $z=e^{i\theta}$.

We can also parametrise $\gamma$ as $e^{i\theta}, \theta \in [-\pi,\pi]$

This means we can express our integral as;

$\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}dz=\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}e^{-i\theta}ie^{i\theta}d\theta=\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}id\theta=0$

So what does the question mean by find all the values of $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}$ ?

It seems to me there is only one ?

Comment: There are two different arcs you can take. Also you calculated the integral wrong and your parameterization is wrong.

Comment: @CameronWilliams do you mean I should evaluate both $\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}id\theta$ and $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}id\theta$ ? wouldn't they both still just give zero ? or should I evaluate $\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}e^{-i\theta}ie^{i\theta}d\theta$ and $\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}e^{-i\theta}ie^{-i\theta}d\theta$ ?

Comment: @exodius The point (amongst other points) is $\int_{\pi}^{-\pi} d\theta \ne 0.$ It is $-2\pi.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen oh shoot sorry , I didn't see my mistake until now , So then I should have the integrals $\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}id\theta=2\pi i$ and $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}id\theta=-2\pi i$ ?

Comment: $e^{i\cdot 0}=1$ and $e^{i\cdot \pi}=-1$

Comment: @exodius It really depends whether you're taking the upper or lower semicircle. If you are taking the upper semicircle, from $1$ to $-1,$ then $e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ is the most natural parametrization. You then get $\int_{0}^\pi e^{-i\theta}ie^{i\theta}d\theta = i\pi.$ ($-\pi$ and $\pi$ are the same angle, so going between these would be going around a whole circle, starting and ending at $-1$).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen if we're taking the lower semicircle does the parametrisation then become $e^{-i\theta} \theta \in [0,\pi]$ ?

Comment: @exodius Yes that is a correct parametrization.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thank you for walking me through where I was going wrong , I understand it alot better now :)

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question below if you figured it out! It could help someone else down the line!

Comment: @CameronWilliams Just finished answering it, I think that's the right idea

Comment: @CameronWilliams, I hope it is anyway, let me know if I made another mistake and I'll edit it for prosperity :)

Comment: @CameronWilliams or let me know if it's right , Just so I know for myself that i have it now :)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen could you check my answer to make sure it's right ?

Comment: @exodius Those are the right answers. Only quibble is that when you say 'there are two ways to parametrize our semi circle' it makes it sound like there is only one path that you are parametrizing in two different ways, when really there are two different possible paths that fit the description of the question (and thus the question is ambiguous).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I edited it to 'there are two semi-circles we can choose from ' :)

Comment: Looks great! Thanks for this. :)

Comment: By the way, you should accept your own answer now! This will prevent the question from being bumped by Community unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a Contour integral $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}dz$ where $\gamma$ is the semicircle going from $1$ to $-1$, then there two arcs which we can integrate over.

There is the lower semi-circle, where we go from $1$ to $-1$ in a clockwise direction, and also the upper semi-circle , where we go from $1$ to $-1$ in an anti-clockwise direction .

With that in mind there are two semi-circles we can choose from;

1) moving in a clockwise direction in which case $\gamma$ can be parametrised as $e^{-i\theta}, \theta \in[0,\pi]$

So here we have $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}dz=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{-ie^{-i\theta }d\theta}{e^{-i\theta}}$, as z=$e^{-i\theta}$ when moving counter-clockwise

$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{-ie^{-i\theta }d\theta}{e^{-i\theta}}=-i\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta=-i[\theta]^{\pi}_{0}=-i\pi$

2) moving in a counter clockwise direction , in which case we can parametrise $\gamma$ as $e^{i\theta}, \theta \in [0,\pi]$

So for this we have $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}dz=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{ie^{i\theta }d\theta}{e^{i\theta}}$, as z=$e^{i\theta}$

$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{ie^{i\theta }d\theta}{e^{i\theta}}=i\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta=i[\theta]^{\pi}_0=\pi i$